# Greatest integer function of this limit.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

The limit :
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\left[\dfrac{\tan x}{x}\right]$$

Which somehow tends to 1, Which is the part I can understand graphically but not intuitively

Plugging values for tanx/x for $10^{-3}$,I get 0.017.

By plugging even smaller values I get values still close to 0.017 so the greatest integer function must tend to zero right?

Can someone point out my flawed logic?

Comment: Can you link to a calculator? Such as Wolfram Alpha (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=tan%2810%5E%28-3%29%29%2F%2810%5E%28-3%29%29&assumption=%22TrigRD%22+-%3E+%22R%22 )..Probably the mistake is entering the wrong expression or using degrees instead of radians.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the wrong limit because you are calculating $\tan x$ as if $x$ is measured in degrees, instead of radians.  Note $$0.017 \approx \frac{\pi}{180}.$$

If you calculate it in radians, for small $x$, we have $$\frac{\tan x}{x} \approx 1.$$

Comment: (-_-;).I hate my life.

Comment: Sir, I don't understand how that would make a difference.If measured in degrees will x be bigger?

Comment: @JustJohan No.  Let me phrase it this way.  In degrees, $\tan 45^\circ = 1$.  But in radians, $\tan \frac{\pi}{4} = 1$.  Note that $x = 45$ in the first case, but $x = \pi/4 \approx 0.785$ in the second case.  So if you use a calculator and you type in $$\frac{\tan 0.01}{0.01}$$ the answer it gives you depends on whether the calculator thinks you mean $0.01$ degrees, or $0.01$ radians.

Comment: yes sir, thank you so much!